# ¿Se puede crear un SR Latch en c++?

Tags: c++, c, lógica

Un SR latch es un dispositivo básico en electrónica. Me gustaría hacer uno en C++, para ello, ya he programado todas las puertas lógicas y comprobado que funciona. Pero ahora, no entiendo como puedo hacerlo debido a la construcción intrinseca de las SR latch

```
}Gates;

struct Latch
{
    bool memorySR = 0;

    bool SR(bool S, bool R)
    {
        //Aquí debería de ir el código del SR Latch

    }


} Latch;
```

Adjunto una imagen de como se realiza un SR Latch. Podría realizarlo con IF en casa caso, pero creo que es mucho mejor hacerlo con puertas lógicas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible hacerlo, e incluso se puede observar cómo el flip-flop SR asíncrono puede generar *glitches* debido a los tiempos de propagamiento de las señales.

Este es un ejemplo, lo he hecho de prisa así que no será el mejor que podrás encontrar. Espero que te sea útil.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SRFlopFlop {
    public:
        SRFlopFlop() : _S(0), _R(0), _Q(0), _nQ(0), _Glitches(0)
        {}
        
        void Update(bool S, bool R) 
        {
            bool glitchDetected;
            _Glitches = 0;
            do
            {
                _Q = !(R | _nQ);
                _nQ = !(S | _Q);
                glitchDetected = (_Q == _nQ);
                
                if (glitchDetected)
                    _Glitches++;
            } while (glitchDetected);
            
            _R = R;
            _S = S;
        }
        
        inline int Q() { return _Q; }
        inline int nQ() { return _nQ; }
        inline int Glitches() { return _Glitches; }
        
        inline int S() { return _S; }
        inline int R() { return _R; }
        
    private:
        int _S;
        int _R;
        int _Q;
        int _nQ;
        int _Glitches;
};


void printStatus(SRFlopFlop &ff)
{
    cout << "Current status:" << endl;
    cout << "  S=" << ff.S() << "  R=" << ff.R() << endl;
    cout << "  Q=" << ff.Q() << " nQ=" << ff.nQ() << "  G=" << ff.Glitches() << endl;
    cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
    SRFlopFlop ff;
    
    cout << "Hello SR-FlipFlop" << endl << endl; 
   
    printStatus(ff);
    
    ff.Update( 0, 1 );
    printStatus(ff);
    
    ff.Update( 1, 0 );
    printStatus(ff);
    
    ff.Update( 0, 1 );
    printStatus(ff);
    
    return 0;
}
```

La salida que da es la siguiente:

```
Hello SR-FlipFlop

Current status:
  S=0  R=0
  Q=0 nQ=0  G=0

Current status:
  S=0  R=0
  Q=1 nQ=0  G=0

Current status:
  S=0  R=1
  Q=0 nQ=1  G=0

Current status:
  S=1  R=0
  Q=1 nQ=0  G=1

Current status:
  S=0  R=1
  Q=0 nQ=1  G=0
```

Si cambias el orden de asignación de las salidas en la función `Update()` y pones este:

```
_nQ = !(S | _Q);
_Q = !(R | _nQ);
```

...verás cómo el valor inicial del flip-flop ahora es distinto. Esta es la salida:

```
Hello SR-FlipFlop

Current status:
  S=0  R=0
  Q=0 nQ=0  G=0

Current status:
  S=0  R=0
  Q=0 nQ=1  G=0

Current status:
  S=0  R=1
  Q=0 nQ=1  G=0

Current status:
  S=1  R=0
  Q=1 nQ=0  G=0

Current status:
  S=0  R=1
  Q=0 nQ=1  G=1
```

Comment: Pues es el mejor que he encontrado. Además literalmente no he encontrado otro y llevo buscando semanas. Muchísimas gracias, no entiendo el código al 100% pero eso ya es trabajo mío. De nuevo, muchas gracias ^^

Comment: Si tienes dudas en alguna parte del código puedes poner un comentario y seguramente cualquiera de los que lo leamos te podrá dar un poco más de información.

Comment: Si encuentras respuestas útiles las puedes marcar, así otros que la necesiten pueden saber que lo han sido para alguien más.